# Why does Gwibber keep asking to authorize my Facebook account, but doesn't add the account after authorizing?

Tags: gwibber

I'm using Gwibber 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I successfully authorized the account with Gwibber, but Gwibber doesn't add my Facebook Account to the broadcasting account list.

What's up with Gwibber?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Was it working before?

Comment: No, this is the first time I use Gwibber. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. There's a [workaround](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-facebook-not-working-with-gwibber.html), though. Be careful replacing code and good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry It didn't work for me :(. Now I can't get the add  account windows...